# How do I add properties to a closure?

Tags: groovy, closures

When I try to add a property to a custom Closure class...

```
class MyClosure extends Closure<Object> {
    def myProperty
    MyClosure() {
        super(null)
    }
    Object doCall(final Closure inner) {
        // do something...
    }
}
println new MyClosure().myProperty
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'myProperty' on null object
```

It seems that this is related to the Closure class that has some behaviour I don't really understand, as when I remove the `implements` part there's no problem:

```
class MyClosure {
    def myProperty
}
println new MyClosure().myProperty
```

So what do I need to do when I want to add a property to a custom closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change closure resolve strategy:

```
class MyClosure extends Closure<Object> {
    def myProperty = "value"

    MyClosure() {
        super(null)
    }

    Object doCall(final Closure inner) {
        // do something...
    }
}

def closure = new MyClosure()
closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.TO_SELF
println closure.myProperty // value
```